# VBA UserForm - Best way to use a TextBox as a decimal numerical input, independently of regional settings?

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I developed an UserForm to ease DataBase inputs for one of my projects.
In this UF, there is a **TextBox dedicated to a numerical value**.

I use this code to avoid text entries :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Right(Me.TextBox1.Value, 1) = "." Or Right(Me.TextBox1.Value, 1) = "," Or _
        Right(Me.TextBox1.Value, 2) = ".0" Or Right(Me.TextBox1.Value, 2) = ",0" Then

    Else
        Me.TextBox1.Value = Val(Me.TextBox1.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

My issue is :

**In USA regional settings**, it is **almost working** : I can input a decimal number with the decimal separator `.`, but every time I enter a zero after the first digit on the right of the separator, the number gets truncated to an integer.

**In French regional settings**, I just **can't input any decimal**, it is always an integer. I can display `.`, `.0`, `,` or `,0` at the end, but when I go further, it gets erase each time gets truncated to an integer.

I saw that we can use `CDbl()` or such functions too, but when I try I get an error every time the is a letter inputted. Maybe a `CDbl()` with an **error handler** using `Val()` would be enough, but I'm not sure and I can't figure out a way to do it properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this for Numeric Textbox with ONE Decimal (See the check for it `If KeyAscii = 46`)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, _
        vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
            '~~> Check to see if there is already a decimal
            If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub
```

Please amend it to suit your needs.

For `,`, the KeyAscii is `44`. You can add that in the above code.

**Edit**

You can use `Application.International(xlCountrySetting)` to check for the country setting and then use `KeyAscii 44` or `KeyAscii 46`. You can also use the API `GetLocaleInfo` to retrieve the Regional Settings.

If i am not wrong then `xlCountrySetting` for France is `33` and for US is `1`

So your code can be written as (**Untested**)

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyDelete, _
        vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
            If Application.International(xlCountrySetting) = 1 Then
                If KeyAscii = 46 Then If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ".") Then KeyAscii = 0
            ElseIf Application.International(xlCountrySetting) = 33 Then
                If KeyAscii = 44 Then If InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, ",") Then KeyAscii = 0
            End If
        Case Else
            KeyAscii = 0
            Beep
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx mate, that was really useful to have another approach to work on!
I just have a little issue as I discovered that some characters can have the same KeyAscii... `$ 36 vbKeyHome`, `& 38 vbKeyUp`, `' 39 vbKeyRight` and `( 40 vbKeyDown`. Any idea on how to avoif this?

Comment: Which characters are you referring to?

Comment: The four that I mentioned, $ and Home have the same KeyAscii (36). I was hoping to use Right() but the character is not enter in the field yet, so I don't really know how avoid it!

Comment: No they dont have same ASC Key

Comment: And yet here they have, I check in debug and msgbox... Maybe it is the French regional settings or something, but they sure have the same value into the procedure. Maybe they don't have the same Ascii, and if you use Chr it won't be the same and yet, I'm sure of what I'm saying as I was able to input them into my field...

Comment: One more astonishing thing : `vbKeyDecimal` value is 110, although `,` is 44 and `.` is 46... Got rid of the previously mentioned doubloons, still working on decimal issues across Regional Settings. But I validate as your code has been very helpful! Thx

Comment: Thanks. I am sorry. I have never worked with french versions. Also I am busy cleaning up my site from hackers so currently tied up else I could have helped you on teamviewer

Comment: Don't worry, I'll find a proper way to do it! If I still have some issues, I'll come and ask a more accurate question! Good luck for your site and if you need some help for security, I know a guy who launched is startup and has won a lot of prizes already! ;)